# With Mongo's geoSpatial queries, how do I find where exactly an intersection occurred?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, gis, geospatial

After drawing coordinates out on a map:

[image: Map]

How do I find the coordinates of *where* the intersection occurred.  I'm able to find what other LineStrings intersect with a specific LineString using this:

```
dbo.collection('loc').find({ "loc" : {
    "$geoIntersects" : {
        "$geometry" : obj //Specific Line String
    }   
} }).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('geointerescts ',result, '-=-=-=-')
})
```

And that returns the correct linestrings that it intersects with including itself.  Something like this when I select Boston to New Orleans:

```
geointerescts  [
  {
    _id: 5e88ecc6f7d52d95b764da87,
    loc: {
      Name: 'Directions from Boston, MA, USA to New Orleans, LA, USA',
      type: 'LineString',
      coordinates: [Array]
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 5e88f5875dfdd396d60e6fd4,
    loc: {
      Name: 'Directions from Chicago, IL, USA to Miami, FL, USA',
      type: 'LineString',
      coordinates: [Array]
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 5e88fe29a44e5ba462a702ad,
    loc: {
      Name: 'Directions from Austin, TX, USA to Charlotte, NC, USA',
      type: 'LineString',
      coordinates: [Array]
    }
  }
]
```

How do I get the points of intersection?  Something like an array of coords in Georgia or Alabama in this example.